# Programmatic connection to SQL Server Compact 4.0

Tags: sql-server-ce, visual-web-developer

I have installed Visual Web Developer 2010 Express along with SQL Server Compact 4.0 and I'm trying to programmatically connect to a database. Whatever I use as a connection string though seems to throw up errors primarily that the database doesn't exist.

The connection string I get from the Database Explorer is:

```
Data Source="C:\Documents and Settings\Amos\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceDB.sdf"
```

If i add a details view the connection in `web.config` is:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=&quot;C:\Documents and Settings\Amos\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceDB.sdf&quot;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

Does anyone know how to set this connection up programmatically?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Remove "&quot" from your connection string
The correct connection string would be`<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\Amos\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceWebsite\MyFaceDB.sdf"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />`

Comment: thanks. i've now found out that I also needed a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe which i've added. however i still get the error SqlCEConnection - type or namespace cannot be found.

Comment: This solution now works for me:

Add a Reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe. You may need to add the new reference by browsing to the dll. Mine was in:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

Temporarily add a DetailsView to your webform so that a connection string is created in webconfig.

The code to then link to the database is:

using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
SqlCeCommand cmd;
SqlCeDataReader dr;